# Magento Currency code in Transaction email showing only base currency code..

Tags: email, currency

I have configured a uk store in my magento site.. Now in order invoices It is showing euro symbol which is the currency code of default store.. I need the The uk pound symbol..

In uk store frontend pound sterlink showing correctly.. I have this problem only in order emails.

Comment: Nope already I configure this correctly.. The problem is only in email.. The currency symbol "EURO" displayed in order invoice.. I have five store.. Except this store all other are working with "Euro".. This store working with (Pound).. In Transaction email only am getting this currency problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I guess you missed here. Set you country currency here

[image]

Comment: Nope already I configure this correctly.. The problem is only in email.. The currency symbol "EURO" displayed in order invoice.. I have five store.. Except this store all other are working with "Euro".. This store working with (Pound).. In Transaction email only am getting this currency problem

Comment: Currency is showing frontend

Comment: yes in frontend currency works fine.. Only mail templates .. I have this problem..